# A menu made up of anchor tags does not work properly on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to display a menu using HTML anchor `<a>` tags as can be seen in the following picture.

[image]

The CSS used is as follows.

```css
a.header-menu:link {
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.header-menu:visited {
    color: #fff;
}

a.header-menu:hover {
    background-color: #f90;
    color: #fff;
}
```

The class `header-menu` is used with `<a>`.

```
<a href="#" class="header-menu">About</a>
```

This works fine on Google Chrome and FireFox but on Internet Explorer (8), the menu disappears as soon as it is clicked.

How to make it work properly on Internet Explorer?

Comment: Does the whole button disappear, (i.e. bg-color turns white)?
Do you see bg-color: #f90; when you hover?
Also what do you see when you inspect the DOM?

Comment: The whole button disappears as soon as it is clicked. Only the link with `background-color: #f90;` is visible on hover without its padded area .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:link` does not style visited links so your text turns white and your background disappears :)

From [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes):

> The :link pseudo-class applies for links that have not yet been visited.

Use a base style:

```css
a.header-menu {
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

then, if wanted, add any differences you want in visited / unvisited links:

```css
a.header-menu:link {
    color: blue;
}

a.header-menu:visited {
    color: purple;
}
```